# How do I calculate the trajectory of a charged particle in a radial electric field?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, electromagnetism, special-relativity

I want to calculate the trajectory of a charged particle in the presence of a radial electric field that is generated from a point charge. Using the normal EOM in radial coordinates, we have the equation $$m\dfrac{d^2r}{dt^2}\, = \,\dfrac{q^2}{4\pi r^2}$$
How do I solve this differential equation? and how do I redo a similar calculation for a massless charged particle (without spin)?

Comment: The equation should be a vector equation: $ m\frac{d^2\vec{r}}{dt^2} = \frac{q^2}{4\pi r^2} \hat{r}$.

Comment: The left-hand-side will have a term of centrapedal force (with angular momentm as a parameter), and  also a term of the first derivative of $r$.

Comment: In the equation a = F/m,  if F is not zero, then, a, approaches infinity as, m, approaches zero.